# How to read component variables from directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I am developing a Angular 2 (rc-4) directive that will check whether component can be viewed under current user authorities and show/hide component accordingly.

I have component identifiers created when the component is initialized. For example, inside the *profile.component.ts* I am generating the id for ProfileComponent (`elementId:string;`)

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['profile.component.css'],
  directives: []
})
export class ProfileComponent {
  @Input('parent-id') parentId:string = "app";
  elementId:string;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elementId = this.parentId + ".profile";
  }
}
```

I have created a Structural Directive following [Angular 2 guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#unless).

```
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[restrict]'
})
export class RestrictDirective {

  authMatrix:any = {
    "guest": {
      "app.dashboard.calendar": false,
      "app.dashboard.profile": false
    },
    "user": {
      "app.dashboard.calendar": false,
      "app.dashboard.profile": true
    },
    "admin": {
      "app.dashboard.calendar": true,
      "app.dashboard.profile": true
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  @Input() set restrict(elementId: string) {
    let user:string = "admin"; // TODO get current logged in user
    let grant:boolean = this.authMatrix[user][elementId]; // TODO user authority service

    if (!grant) {
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

So, in order to block or allow a component, I need that component's id to be passed to the directive. At the moment, I have hard-coded the component id ("app.dashboard.profile") to the directive input as follows,

```
<app-profile *restrict="'app.dashboard.profile'" [parent-id]="elementId" ></app-profile>
```

This setup works. But I want to get component id from the associated component's variable rather than hard-coding it in the html tag. Is there a way that I can access variables inside my Component (ProfileComponent) from my Directive (RestrictDirective)?

Comment: That looks weird: `[parent-id]="elementId`. `parent-id` and `elementId` are both properties of `ProfileComponent`? I don't get where from you want to pass what and where to.

Comment: I'm trying to keep a common structure for all components when creating ids. All components have parentId and elementId variables. What is unclear here is that I am binding `elementId` variable of DashboardComponent (parent component of ProfileComponent) to the input variable `parentId` ('parent-id') of ProfileComponent.

`profile.parentId <-- dashboard.elementId`

Comment: You can inject `DashboardComponent` to `ProfileComponent` and read the `elementId` from there but this creates tight coupling. I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Günter. Injecting components wouldn't work in my scenario since components are reused in multiple locations.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I don't think there is another way.

Comment: I have a similar question thanks for posting